# Where can I find ideas for strategies?

Tags: finance, finance-mathematics, statistical-finance, financial-engineering

Every book I read refers me to many other books, there is practically no way I can read all this text in my life time. Once and for all, where is the best place to fish for ideas?

Comment: That's what's interesting about this business, there are always new things to learn and new things to be discovered. Isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of different sources out there where you can find various quantitative strategies.

Usually, different blog aggregators like https://www.r-bloggers.com post on their websites interesting new approaches and techniques.

You can also find great deal of information on Quantopian's dedicated page here: https://www.quantopian.com/posts/trading-strategy-ideas-thread

ssrn.com and arxiv.org also may be useful.